# Xcode take relative path when I add new file

Tags: xcode, relative-path, file-location

I have issue with xcode and cause issue with my team when I comments my code. when I add new swift file it always take relative path from root to file location in project not the absolute path. do any one know how to fix it?
[image]

Comment: Something odd with the way you created / added the Group (Folder)? What do you see if you select the Folder containing that file?

Comment: I see take the relative path

Comment: Does it show the full path, like when you have the file selected? Here's what I see (Group/Folder selected ... File in that Group/Folder selected) in a quick test: https://i.stack.imgur.com/StTFX.png

Comment: the full path work fine is the dropdown is the problem with /../../../../../ with relative path

Comment: to fixed it I have to remove the reference folder and added on folder drag and drop again :(